# What is | (Pipe) symbol used for in Python Opencv functions ( cv2.threshold)

Tags: python, opencv3.0, opencv

**I know this is **Bitwise OR** but what I want to know is what itis doing in the given function and how it works for function call**

I have seen a couple of codes using `|` inside the opencv functions such as

```
t, im = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

What is the meaning of this `|`? What does is signifies and how can I use this `|` in a random function `foo(x|y)`?

Comment: It's just a bitwise OR https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

Comment: Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types

Comment: As to _why_ this is a bitwise OR: This is a common method in other languages (such as C/C++ that OpenCV is written in) and (e.g. network) protocols to encode a set of flags: Each flag gets assigned a number that's a power of two (1, 2, 4, 8, ...). You can then OR them together without information loss, and extract the value of a single flag with a bitwise AND.

Comment: The two constants are ORed together and passed as a single parameter to the function which just sees the combined result and has no idea how it was provided in the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to use these values just as you would normally. BUT note it's usual to define the constants being Or-ed so that each one sets only one bit when two or more values are OR-ed together.

In a function which would use these values, you would normally be testing eahc of the bots which is simplest done by AND-ing with the value, as in `myfn()` in the example below.

As someone else said in the asnwers, this style of bitwise OR-ing is/was common in C/C++ code implementations, and e.g. opencv python is a wrapper over the underlying opencv C++ implementation. Personally if I were designing a Python API I'd use separate named parameters for each flag, i.e. avoid the OR-ing.

For example:

```
import cv2

def showvalue(v):
    print( f"{v=} {bin(v)=} {hex(v)=}" )

showvalue( cv2.THRESH_OTSU )
showvalue( cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV )
showvalue( cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU )

abit = 0b0010
bbit = 0b0100

def myfn( v ):
    print( "+++++++" )
    print( f"{v=}" )
    if v & abit:
        print( f"abit is set" )
    if v & bbit:
        print( f"bbit is set" )
    print( "-------" )

myfn(abit)
myfn(bbit)
myfn(abit| bbit)
```

output:

```
v=8 bin(v)='0b1000' hex(v)='0x8'
v=1 bin(v)='0b1' hex(v)='0x1'
v=9 bin(v)='0b1001' hex(v)='0x9'
+++++++
v=2
abit is set
-------
+++++++
v=4
bbit is set
-------
+++++++
v=6
abit is set
bbit is set
-------
```

Answer (score 1):

It's common for coders to cram a bunch of options into a single variable. If you look at the constants assigned to the various [ThresholdTypes](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaa9e58d2860d4afa658ef70a9b1115576) in binary format, it's a little easier to understand

```
import cv2

print('THRESH_BINARY:     ', format(cv2.THRESH_BINARY, '#08b'))
print('THRESH_BINARY_INV: ', format(cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, '#08b'))
print('THRESH_TRUNC:      ', format(cv2.THRESH_TRUNC, '#08b'))
print('THRESH_TOZERO:     ', format(cv2.THRESH_TOZERO, '#08b'))
print('THRESH_TOZERO_INV: ', format(cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV, '#08b'))
print('THRESH_MASK:       ', format(cv2.THRESH_MASK, '#08b'))
print('THRESH_OTSU:       ', format(cv2.THRESH_OTSU, '#08b'))
print('THRESH_TRIANGLE:   ', format(cv2.THRESH_TRIANGLE, '#08b'))
```

which gives:

```
THRESH_BINARY:      0b000000
THRESH_BINARY_INV:  0b000001
THRESH_TRUNC:       0b000010
THRESH_TOZERO:      0b000011
THRESH_TOZERO_INV:  0b000100
THRESH_MASK:        0b000111
THRESH_OTSU:        0b001000
THRESH_TRIANGLE:    0b010000
```

The pipe (|) is a bitwise or and sets the output bit to 1 if one or both input bits are 1, otherwise 0. In your example, the options `THRESH_BINARY_INV` and `THRESH_OTSU` can both be selected with a bitwise or. In that case the 1st and 4 bits are set and `0b001001` is sent to the function.

It gets a little weirder if you try to use

```
cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV
```

In that case the first bit gets set (`0b00000001`) and you will get an inverted threshold. In this case, `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` is effectively ignored.

A less confusing example is in the Qt library, the possible values for [InputMethodHints](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#InputMethodHint-enum) are all bitwise exclusive:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

print('Qt.ImhHiddenText:       ', format(Qt.ImhHiddenText, '#011b'))
print('Qt.ImhSensitiveData:    ', format(Qt.ImhSensitiveData, '#011b'))
print('Qt.ImhNoAutoUppercase:  ', format(Qt.ImhNoAutoUppercase, '#011b'))
print('Qt.ImhPreferNumbers:    ', format(Qt.ImhPreferNumbers, '#011b'))
print('Qt.ImhPreferUppercase:  ', format(Qt.ImhPreferUppercase, '#011b'))
print('Qt.ImhPreferLowercase:  ', format(Qt.ImhPreferLowercase, '#011b'))
print('Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText: ', format(Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText, '#011b'))
print('Qt.ImhDate:             ', format(Qt.ImhDate, '#011b'))
print('Qt.ImhTime:             ', format(Qt.ImhTime, '#011b'))

Qt.ImhHiddenText:        0b000000001
Qt.ImhSensitiveData:     0b000000010
Qt.ImhNoAutoUppercase:   0b000000100
Qt.ImhPreferNumbers:     0b000001000
Qt.ImhPreferUppercase:   0b000010000
Qt.ImhPreferLowercase:   0b000100000
Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText:  0b001000000
Qt.ImhDate:              0b010000000
Qt.ImhTime:              0b100000000
```

You can bitwise 2 or more or all options and not get a collision.

Answer (score 0):

It is OR Bitwise operator. Sets each bit to 1 if one or both of the two bits is 1.

Let's define a function

```
def print_if_1(number):
    if number == 1:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```

and two variables `a` and `b`

```
a=1
b=0
```

Now lets first verify:

```
print(a)
```

> 1

```
print(b)
```

> 0

And here is how we can use pipe in this function:

```
print(a|b)
```

> 1

Comment: I know this is `OR` in normal case iut how it is used in a function like it is used in the above given function. And if I have to create a function , how can I?